# show records in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have to fetch all records from database and display them in tableLayout. I have done first part. I have created a method to fetch records from database and stored them in List. Now my problem is how to put the records from List to Table Layout?
Here is my method:

```
public List<Hospital> getallrecords(){
     List<Hospital> info = new LinkedList<Hospital>();
     String query = "SELECT * FROM " + "PATIENT_INFO";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Hospital hospital = null;
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
            hospital = new Hospital();
            hospital.setMRNo(cursor.getString(1));
            hospital.setTitle(cursor.getString(2));
            hospital.setName(cursor.getString(3));
            hospital.setPrename(cursor.getString(4));
            hospital.setPredecessorname(cursor.getString(5));
            hospital.setPhone1(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)));
            hospital.setPhone2(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)));
            hospital.setAddress(cursor.getString(8));

            info.add(hospital);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    return info;

}
```

Comment: So, What is your problem/

Comment: how to add records from List to table Layout? How to display them?

Comment: I have posted an answer, Please have a look and let me know If you are having any problem.

Comment: No its not working... No records are being displayed

Comment: Forget about the list; just use a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).

Comment: @CL Can you post a relevant link or example? I didn't get any solution still

Answer (score 0):

You can use following way to fetch data in table layout.

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutId);
```

for(i=0;i<info.size();i++){
  TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
  row .setId(i);
  row .setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

  TextView tile= new TextView(this);
  title.setId(200+i); 
  tile.setText(info.getTitle());
  title.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
  title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  row.addView(title);

  TextView name= new TextView(this);
  name.setId(200+i);
  name.setText(info.getName());
  name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  row.addView(name);
//same as you can add as many column as you want.

  tablelayout.addView(row, new  TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

}

Or You can use the ListView (As It is an better way to display list data):
Please follow following tutorial :
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: Can I use ListView instead of TableLayout ? If yes, do u have relevant example?

Comment: Yes of course, ListView Will be the best way to show the arraylist data in a row.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_showalll);
         LoginDatabaseAdapter a = new LoginDatabaseAdapter(this);
         a.open();
         List<Hospital> results = a.getallrecords();

Comment: how to use the example with database?